# Add alternative language to SharePoint Online Sites PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I am trying to Add Alternative Language to my SharePoint sites using  PowerShell:

```
$sitetenant = "https://mytenat-admin.sharepoint.com"
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-SPOService -Url $sitetenant -Credential $credential
$sites = Get-SPOSite "https://mytenat.sharepoint.com/site"

foreach($site in $sites) 
{
      $culture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo(1033)
      $site.AddSupportedUICulture($culture)
      $site.Update()
}
```

I think this method doesn't exist in SharePoint Online?

Comment: Open the RootWeb of the site collection and pass the LCID of your desired language to AddSupportedUICulture method. E.g. ```$web = $site.OpenWeb(); $web.AddSupportedUICulture(1031)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) cmdlets are pretty limited in this regard, i would suggest to utilize CSOM API, in particular [`Web.AddSupportedUILanguage` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.addsupporteduilanguage.aspx) to add alternative language as demonstrated below:

```
$siteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"
$UserName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = ""


$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

$web = $ctx.Site.RootWeb
$lcid = 1049
$web.AddSupportedUILanguage($lcid)
$web.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```