# Need to Add Translators for Language in SharePoint Online using PnP PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Using this link
[Add alternative language to SharePoint Online Sites PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161599/add-alternative-language-to-sharepoint-online-sites-powershell)
I have enable Site languages and added alternative Language as well.
tried to add translators for the alternative Language but I couldn't find anyway to do that, Is there a way to do it using PnP PowerShell or need to add it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint Online: Add Alternate Language using PowerShell**

```
#Set variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"

#Add Welsh
$LanguageID = 1106 
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin 
 
#Get the Web
$Web = Get-PnPWeb
 
#Add Alternate Language
$Web.IsMultilingual = $True
$Web.AddSupportedUILanguage($LanguageID)
$Web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery

#Get the Web
$Web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes RegionalSettings.InstalledLanguages
 
#Get Available Languages
$Web.RegionalSettings.InstalledLanguages
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I followed the same way, but I couldn't add translators to added languages.

Comment: Hi DeMel Code. Thanks for your reply. Is there an error message/code? Please attach a screenshot if you can.

Comment: There is no error EchoDu_MSFT, I just want to find a way to add translators to Add Alternate Language using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Adding translators is not part of the standard multilingual site, it is part of the Multilingual Page Publishing feature that can be added to Communication sites.

You have to enable the feature first.  Note that activating the feature wipes out the languages you added, you have to add the supported UI languages afterwards.  The feature ID is 24611c05-ee19-45da-955f-6602264abaf8

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I need to add translators.

Comment: I don't know a simple way to add translators, but I can tell you the complicated way.

After you add the feature and add the UI languages, you will see a bunch of site properties with names starting with "_SPTranslationSetting_" , for example  "_SPTranslationSetting_CDlnZR1wR0uzIhlHBDl1pw==_de-DE".  That contains the list of translators in the form of numbers.  Those numbers correspond to the ID of the translator in the hidden User Information List.

Comment: martin-laplante thanks for quick replay, I will try it.